# Flask MySQL hosted database connection: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, flask, router

**EDIT**

I managed to resolve the issue.  I needed to add my home IP address to the list of "Allowable Hosts" on my site's management portal.  I can now connect to my remote database with my app locally.

---

I have a flask app that can connect to a hosted database and I wanted to start managing the code through a git repository.  I have the application working locally, however the app can no longer connect to the hosted database.  I'm sure the issue has something to do with my router, but the specific error I get is:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'ip-address-of-my-router' (using password: YES)")
```

The host address I pass in is mysql.mywebsite.com, however when my app attempts to establish a connection, it's trying to connect to ip-address-of-my-router instead of my hosted database.

Does anyone know what I need to do to prevent this swap from occurring?  Temporarily I can create a local database and populate it with sample data, but I'd really like to be able to connect to the actual database while developing the app instead of working with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment to my post, but if you end up down here:

I managed to resolve the issue. I needed to add my home IP address to the list of "Allowable Hosts" on my site's management portal. I can now connect to my remote database with my app locally.